# WPF binding to an already bound property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

What can I do if I want to bind to some property which is already bound to something else?

In my case, I got a window which has a TextBox. The Text property of this TextBox is data bound to a combo box to it's selectedItem. My Window class got a public string property which I want to update with whatever value is in the TextBox so I wanted to data bind with the Text property but as I said, it's already bound.

How can I update my property with the text in TextBox? Must it use a routed event of TextChanged or can I do it via Xaml?

Also specifically with properties you define them yourself in your window.cs ... how can you bind them to the TextBox.Text? I tried doing it with the `<Window>` declaration, meaning `<Window MyProperty={Binding ...} />` but the property is not recognized there. Why and how do I do it?

Comment: You can bind both, `ComboBox` and `TextBox`, to `MyProperty` in your `Window` class

Comment: @dkozl ok good. If you can write an answer with a code example, I'll accept it

Comment: @YonatanNir, I strongly suggest you use the [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), which has become the de facto standard in WPF development. It would make it much easier to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I want to use it but I'm not sure how to in this case. If you could show an example, I'd be glad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this easily using the MVVM pattern.

ViewModel:

```
public class ChooseCategoryViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string[] _categories =
        { "Fruit", "Meat", "Vegetable", "Cereal" };

    public string[] Categories
    {
        get { return _categories; }
    }

    private string _selectedCategory;
    public string SelectedCategory
    {
        get { return _selectedCategory; }
        set
        {
            _selectedCategory = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCategory");
                            if (value != null && CategoryName != value)
                                CategoryName = value;
        }
    }

    private string _categoryName;
    public string CategoryName
    {
        get { return _categoryName; }
        set
        {
            _categoryName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CategoryName");
            if (Categories.Contains(value))
            {
                SelectedCategory = value;
            }
            else
            {
                SelectedCategory = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}" /> 
<TextBox Text="{Binding CategoryName}" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure about something here.. The SelectedItem is chosen by the user in the Window when choosing an option from the combo box.. Why did you bind it as the target from the SelectedCategory property? How does it get updated? 
Also, I see that the TextBox Text is being updated with the CategoryName but that didn't answer my question - what if there's another property in the ViewModel which you want to set with the Text from the TextBox?

Comment: @YonatanNir, when the user selects a value from the ComboBox, it updates the SelectedCategory, which updates the CategoryName in the ViewModel (actually I had forgotten that part in my code, I updated it), which in turns updates the TextBox. If you type something in the TextBox, it updates the CategoryName, which updates the SelectedCategory, which updates the ComboBox selected item.

Comment: So eventually it must be done with code behind? I can't somehow use XAML alone?

Comment: @YonatanNir, it's in the ViewModel, not in code-behind. Even though the binding system is quite powerful, you can't do everything in XAML.